# Как удалить ветку Git и локально, и удаленно?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote

Я хочу удалить ветку и локально, и удаленно из проекта на GitHub.

**Локально удаляется**

```
> git branch -D feature/experiment
> Deleted branch feature/experiment (was 863225e).
```

**Попытки удалить ветку на сервере**

```
> git branch -d origin/feature/experiment
error: branch 'origin/feature/experiment' not found.
> git branch -rd origin/feature/experiment
Deleted remote branch origin/feature/experiment (was 863225e).
> git pull
* [new branch]      feature/experiment -> origin/feature/experiment
```

Непонятно, что означает "Deleted remote branch", если на самом деле ветвь не была удалена? Последующая команда `pull` показывает это.

Что нужно делать, чтобы удалить ветвь и локально, и на сервере?

Comment: `git push origin --delete feature/experiment` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, я еще помучаюсь выбором

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

В Git v1.7.0, вы можете удалить удалённую ветку, используя

```
git push origin --delete <branchName>
```

что легче запомнить, чем

```
git push origin :<branchName>
```

добавленное в Git v1.5.0 "чтобы удалить удалённую ветку или метку".

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: Почему интересно автор считает, что первый вариант запомнить легче?

Comment: Собственно про это и пишут в первом комменте к оригиналу: "If you know the syntax git push origin local_branch:remote_branch, then the syntax to delete a branch with git push origin :remote_branch is kind of cute. There's a void before the :".

Comment: @dzhioev: он более человеческим языком написан. Да, в том чтобы пушить void в ветку есть что-то особенное, мне в свое время очень понравилась идея.

Comment: нет там ничего "особенного". просто люди не думали головой, и не проектировали api. Просто нагромождали кучу противоречивого синтаксиса. Чтобы переобуться: "Значит так, сначала отстрелите себе обе ступни, потом начинайте выращивать новые ступни. Для этого..."

Answer (score 3):

Удалить ветку в remote репозитории можно так:

```
git push origin :feature/experiment
```

`-rd` не работает потому, что он удаляет только локальную remote-tracking ветку. Если соответствующая ветка на была удалена из remote репозитория, remote-tracking ветка будет создана заново при следующем вызове команды `fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

Удалить ветку в удаленном репозитории:

```
$ git branch -rD origin/feature/experiment
```

Comment: Это часть уже данного чужого ответа. Не надо таких дублирующих ответов.

Answer (score 0):

локально у себя в VScode удаляю таким образом, где name_branch - это название ветки

```
git branch -D name_branch
```

или

```
git branch -d name_branch
```

Параметр -d означает --delete, который удалит локальную ветвь, только в случае, если вы смерджили её с какой-то из веток.
Опция -D обозначает --delete --force, которая удаляет ветку независимо от ее статуса push или merge, так что будьте осторожны при её использовании!

Comment: Так вопрос как раз не в удалении локально, а в удалении на сервере. Буквально начало вопроса: "Локально удаляется `git branch -D feature/experiment`"

Comment: Как удалить ветку Git и локально, и удаленно?   Вот так звучит вопрос, я описал как это осуществить локально. Пробовал git branch -D feature/experiment мне не помогло, разобравшись решил добавить.

Comment: Значит вы отвечаете на какой-то другой вопрос.