# Можно ли переименовать опубликованную ветку в Git?

Tags: git

Создал я ветку, например, mycode. Затем внёс необходимые изменения, сделал commit, push. Теперь подумал, что буду делать ещё несколько похожих веток с похожим функционалом и переименую первую в api_mycode. Это можно как-то сделать?

Comment: Уже был подобный вопрос: [**Как переименовать основную ветку Git**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542158/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-git)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753888/5000805

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Для переименования ветки, загруженной на удалённый сервер, нужно вначале переименовать ветку локально, а затем выгрузить изменения обратно, удалив предыдущую ветку на сервере.

```
git branch -m старое_название новое_название
git push origin :старое_название новое_название
```

Во второй строчке обратите внимание на двоеточие перед старым именем ветки — это команда для удаления ветки на сервере.

Comment: Т.е. специально удалять ветку старую не надо, второй командой `git push origin :старое_название новое_название` она удалится автоматически?

Comment: да, можно совместить удаление ветки и отправку новой, переименнованной; https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471241/183314

Comment: Господа, я прошу учесть, что в вопросе речь идет о переименовании ветки, а не о ее удалении, что далеко не то же самое, т.к. ветка может иметь историю, которую нужно сохранить в ветке с новым названием. У меня сейчас есть именно такая проблема. Все что удалось нагуглить, включая и гитхабовскую книжку, сводится именно к удалению старой ветки

Comment: @vitaliy4us, уточните, что вы имеете виду под "ветка может иметь историю". Речь про фиксацию и её предков, куда ссылалась ветка с предыдущим названием? Так такая история изменений останется. Если речь про reflog, то он доступен только в локальном репозитории. Насколько мне известно, через протокол Git вы не можете управлять этим журналом в удалённом репозитории на сервере.

Comment: @vitaliy4us ветка - это просто название, назначенное коммиту. От того, что вы удаляете старое название и добавляете новое, история коммитов никак не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего переименовать прямо на GitHub, там есть такая кнопка.

[image: Переименование]

Но локально все равно придётся тоже переименовать и обновить связи.
Причем всем коллегам.

```
git branch -m bad-branch-name corrected-branch-name
git fetch origin
git branch -u origin/corrected-branch-name corrected-branch-name
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел подтверждения о сохранении "истории ветки".
Поэтому пишу этот ответ где разобрался используя документацию [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management)

**Внимание**

> 1. Не переименовывайте ветки, которые всё ещё используются другими участниками.
> 2. Не переименовывайте ветку в master/main/mainline, не читая инструкцию по измени названия главной ветки.

**Теперь к смене имени ветки**

`$ git branch --move bad-branch-name corrected-branch-name`
или
`$ git branch -m bad-branch-name corrected-branch-name`

Таким образом мы сменим название ветки только локально

Отправим изменения на удаленный репозиторий
`$ git push --set-upstream origin corrected-branch-name`

> Проверить изменения можно командой
> `$ git branch --all`
> Там будут выведен список веток локального и удаленного репозитория
> `* текущая ветка`
>   `другие локальные ветки`
>   `remotes/origin/текущие удаленные ветки`

На текущий момент у нас останется старая ветка на удаленном репозитории. Можно удостовериться, что история перешла в новую ветку. Удалить старую ветку можно командой
`$ git push origin --delete bad-branch-name`

Так мы полностью заменим старое имя ветки на новое.

Comment: Так а в чём разница с принятым ответом?

Comment: Разница в том, что я подробнее описал решение данного вопроса, и мой ответ очень подойдет для новичков в Git. А ваш комментарий считаю не компетентным.