# GitHub как залить проект

Tags: git, github, push, main, merge

Жутко бесит git и github. Мне программировать проще, чем пользоваться ими. Собственно, вопрос:
Я хочу просто залить свой проект на github, но сталкиваюсь с кучей трудностей.
Вот я создал новый публичный репозиторий на github'e. Затем выполнил в git'e следующие команды:

```
cd "папка"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Single commit"
git remote -v
git remote add origin "адрес"
git push origin mainbranch
```

После этого весь проект вроде как залился на github, но завис где-то в каком-то промежуточном состоянии и что с ним делать дальше я не пойму. Никаких вменяемых кнопок на сайте я не нашел. И дело в том, что я даже не знаю как это правильно искать в google. Вот скриншоты текущего состояния репозитория:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Запушили ветку mainbranch, а на сайте смо́трите ветку main — нестыковочка

Comment: Ну это у меня в git'e она называется `mainbranch`, а на github'e - `main`. Но ведь на github'e ветка `main` - это основная? Как мне из ветки `mainbranch` переместить проект в основную `main` не подскажете?

Comment: [Основы ветвления и слияния](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), [Управление ветками](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), [Можно ли переименовать опубликованную ветку в Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704278)

Comment: Правда, из-за того, что ветка mainbranch почему-то не основана на ветке main — вам теперь будет больно. При попытке слияния вы получите merge-коммит, а при попытке тупо сделать push одной ветки на место другой ветки git нажалуется, что ветки не связаны друг с другом, и заставит использовать force для принудительной замены

Comment: Ну и да: «я создал новый публичный репозиторий на github'e» и «git init» — вы зачем-то создали два репозитория, оттого теперь и страдаете, видимо

Comment: Может быть. Мне просто github этот нервы съедает, оттого я делаю все в некоторой спешке и вообще постоянно путаюсь в его устройстве.

Comment: Создать два репозитория и потом доказывать гитхабу, что на самом деле это один и тот же, - это путь для тех, кто любит создавать проблемы на пустом месте.  Есть путь проще: Создайте чистый репозиторий на гитхабе (с одним README файлом) средствами гитхаба.  Никаких git init!  Потом склонируйте репу гитхаба к себе локально через https-ссылку.  И только потом добавляйте свои файлы, коммитьте и пушьте.

Comment: ОПу явно требуется какой-то ликбез по гит. @ESkri Клонирование создает второй репозиторий точно так же, как и git init. Созданный гитхабом коммит с readme можно было бы без проблем подтянуть уже после git init.