# В название ветки случайно попал спец символ, который github не распознает. Теперь нельзя произвести никакие действия с этой веткой

Tags: git, github

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нельзя удалить ветку, сделать pull request или вообще перейти по этой ветке для просмотра.
На текущий момент, все комиты из ветки я спас, теперь необходимо удалить эту ветку. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как ветку запушили через инструменты или консоль, так и удалите. github только отображает это дело, весь контроль всё ещё у вас.

Answer (score 3):

вообще удалить ветку не сложно: [Как удалить ветку Git и локально, и удаленно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471231/178576)

некоторая сложность наступает при попытке набрать её имя в эмуляторе терминала.

---

попробуем для экспериментов создать ветку с нечитаемым именем:

```
$ git co -b "шт$(echo ш | iconv -t cp1251)т"
Switched to a new branch 'шт�т'
```

довольно похоже на то, что у вас на картинке.

если у вас настроено автодополнение, имя начинается с читаемого символа и нет схожих имён, то попробуйте набрать начало имени и нажать <kbd>tab</kbd>.

в предложенном мною примере я набрал:

```
$ git branch -d шт
```

и нажал <kbd>tab</kbd>. имя дополнилось:

```
$ git branch -d шт�т
```

если сейчас нажате <kbd>enter</kbd>, то локальная ветка благополучно удалится. аналогично сработает и (если версия программы *git* у вас выше или равна `1.7.0`):

```
$ git remote origin --delete шт
```

нажатие <kbd>tab</kbd> дополнит имя.

---

если с автодополнением не получается, подсмотреть реальное имя можно внутри самого хранилища. локальные ветки здесь:

```
$ ls .git/refs/heads/
 master  'шт'$'\370''т'
```

ветки в хранилище `origin` — здесь:

```
$ ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/
 master  'шт'$'\370''т'
```

просто скопируйте (мышкой) вот эту «абракадабру» — `'шт'$'\370''т'` и подставьте в нужное место нужной команды.

---

если и мышки нет, получить имя файла в каталоге `.git/refs/heads/` и/или `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` можно каким-нибудь из упомянутых здесь способов: [Ubuntu перейти в папку с названием на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451145/178576)